# cron file to update the database sequentially after every run

Tags: php, mysql, tabs, cron

im redesigning a mmorpg game and im in a bit of a pickle on this one.
i have the following code on the daily cron file.

```
dbn("update mygame set event = '11' where event = '10'");
```

now...

this file runs once a day. i would like to update the database in a way such
day 1 ----- event =10,
day 2 ----- event =11,
day 3 ----- event =12 ...etc,
in other words,
once the event is set it will automatically update itself till it dies out.
Hence day 1

```
dbn("update mygame set event = '10' where event = '9'");
```

day 2

```
dbn("update mygame set event = '11' where event = '10'");
```

so on and so forth.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance for reading.

Answer (score 2):

1) Make your event column a numeric type like an int, not a string containing a number

2) `dbn("UPDATE mygame SET event = event + 1")`

However, you probably don't need this column at all. If all it does is count days, then store the start date and COMPUTE the number of days elapsed wherever you're using that value. You won't have to run any query each day.

Comment: how would i add a timestamp in the database like that?

Comment: The same way you added the number, in the INSERT query

Comment: dbn("update mygame set event = '11' where event = '10 set time = [time]'"); ?

Comment: my problem is how will the cron know how to stop and go every click.

Comment: No... you store the timestamp instead of having an event column at all. And you don't have a daily UPDATE query anymore, so I wasn't suggesting you add to that. If the event is a property of how many days it's been since the row was created, then it does not need to be stored and updated each day as it's derived data. You can compute the current event by computing the difference between the current date and the date you started the game at any time.

Comment: mind puting that in code? im not really getting it. im having a brain^&*( right now.

Comment: When you create the game (this row you were previously updating once a day): `INSERT INTO mygame (somecol, anothercol, created_at) VALUES (somevalue, someothervalue, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`. When you want to know how many days have elapsed, `SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, created_at) FROM mygame`.

Comment: RIGHT!!!!... i'll tryt that and get back at you later.   one more thing... how would i compare it to the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mygame
  SET event=event+1
  WHERE <useful condition>
```

Comment: i tried that , that way it will simply cycle through all the stages in a single run. i need it to update the stages every run. day 1, stage 1, day 2 - stage 2,... etc.

Comment: Setting a column to 11 where it's 10 is completely equivalent to adding 1 to it. It can't be both right and wrong.

Comment: all these comands are in a cron file if i ask the cron to update the event to +1 it returns me to 0 in a single run because it cycles through all the updates. i need it to update it every click of the cron file.

Comment: "it cycles through all the updates" ← I don't know what this is supposed to mean, but I'm certain that it's wrong.

Comment: it sets event to 0 where the default value is because it adds all the updates in a single run from 1 to 12 and back to 0.

Comment: Yeah... no. You're just horribly, horribly confused.

Comment: ill try your version where ill place the condition with the time stamp as well though. that might work.

Comment: A single UPDATE query cannot change a column's value more than once. It will not "cycle" anything, and adding 1 to 12 will never give you anything other than 13.

Comment: there are 12 events all lined up with updates. when i run the cron file with 3 events from event 10 to 11 to event 6 , it shows all the events happened in one click. thats what i mean. it skips event 11 and goes directly to 6. im not sure if im explaining myself. when im setting event from 10 to 11 now the line underneath picks it up and updates it from 11 to 6 in one shot.

Comment: That's because you've goofed it up. What is the cycle you're looking for?

Comment: an event is trigered by a user, once this even is trigered an event number is inserted in the database events,he cron file, which runs once a day checks the database events and progresses them daily, from event 1, which was user trigered, to event 2, the second day, to event 3, s0 on and so forth.

Comment: That's what my statement does. You're using the wrong condition.

Comment: well the cron file is only runing once a day so an event update per click would do it.